# Conducting cylinder by dielectric interface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, dielectric, method-of-images

To help me with a project I'm working on, I attempted to solve what I thought was an easy problem. There is an infinite, conducting cylinder of radius $R$ at some potential $V$, located a distance $b$ from a dielectric interface. Rudimentary image included.

[image: Problem Layout]

I want to find the potential in the half space including the cylinder.
My first thought was to solve using a charged wire, using the image method, but the solution that gives does not have circular equipotential surfaces. I though perhaps to write the potential as a Fourier sum, but the different geometries (of the interface and cylinder) are making it very difficult for me to write boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would proceed is first to exchange the spherical electrode by a point charge at the centre :
$$
    Q = \frac{VR}{K}
$$
With :
$$
    K = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}
$$

Then that charge would have an image across the dielectric surface, the method has been described quite well in [introduction to electrodynamics](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=david+j+griffiths+introduction+to+electrodynamics) or [here](http://www.physicspages.com/tag/method-of-images/)

The image charge will itself have a image charge inside the wire, see [here](http://www.df.unipi.it/%7Emacchi/TEACHING/FISICA2/PROBLEMS/imagecharge-sphere.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0607145) on how to calculate it.

The you just repeat the process until the solutions converges, the potential will be the one induced by all the image charges. (See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185004/38117) for more details on the process)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was obviously not apparent to people reading this question - there is a perfectly conducting, infinite cylinder (with a circular cross-section) at some distance from the plane of separation. After some research, I am convinced there is not analytic solution to the problem, and instead used numeric methods to receive an approximate solution.