# Capacitance of a system of spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

> Consider a system of two conducting spheres, as follows
>
> [image]
>
> The outer sphere contains a charge $+Q$ and the inner surface is neutral.

What would be the capacitance of the system?
 We know $C=\frac{q}{V}$. But here the potential difference between the spheres is 0, so will it be correct to say, that the capacitance of the system is infinity. but if I consider this whole system as a single conductor and see its potential difference with respect to infinity, I get $C=4\pi \epsilon _0(3R)$.
Now suppose I earth the inner sphere. then to make the potential of inner sphere=$0$, $\frac{Q}{3}$ charge will flow into the earth. So now a potential difference will occur between the spheres. Then the capacitance of the system will not be $\infty$. and there will be a potential difference with respect to infinity. so how exactly can we calculate the capacitance?
Please help me solve this doubt. I am really confused here. I think I have not understood what the term "capacitance" means exactly.

Comment: You will have two capacitors in parallel.

Comment: If the inner sphere is uncharged, there is no potential difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for concentric spheres $(a<b)$,

$$
\begin{pmatrix} V_a \\ V_b \end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} \\
  \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{b}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  Q_a \\ Q_b
\end{pmatrix}$$

- The matrix is known as elastance matrix which is the inverse of the capacitance matrix.

The mutual capacitance is given by

$$C=\frac{Q_a}{V_a-V_b}=\frac{4\pi \epsilon_0ab}{b-a}$$

- Note that there's no dependence on charges on the outer sphere due to Gauss' Law.
- In usual practice, the outer sphere is earthed so as $V_b=0$.

See also another post of mine [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377887/modified-coulombs-law-hypothetical-and-conductor/377897#377897).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not connect the inner sphere to ground or some other potential , the inner sphere does not matter you can choose any r for it, you just have the capacitance of the outer sphere .

Comment: so, if i connect the inner sphere to ground the capacitance will be q/v where q is the charge on the outer surface of inner sphere. and if it is not connected to ground capacitance will be seen for the outer sphere wrt infinity. am i correct?

Comment: yes you are right, but v depend of R and r.